# Switching to Ubuntu - can Betterbird history carry over?

Tags: windows, thunderbird

I have quite a bit of email that I'd like to save and it's in my Betterbird profile in windows. I'd like to switch to Ubuntu, but am not sure I can carry my profile over so that I can access old emails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Web page for Betterbird says: "You can install Betterbird at the same time as Thunderbird and run them on the same profile. That means that you can try out Betterbird with zero hassle, and go back to Thunderbird if you don't like it". For me that means that profiles are fully compatible between Thunderbird and Betterbird, therefore migration should be possible.

Comment: @user535733 Their web page says "we're now also shipping Linux binaries, there are packages for Arch Linux and a Flatpak".

Answer (score 1):

[Betterbird](https://www.betterbird.eu/releasenotes/index.html) is a fork of Thunderbird. The profiles are compatible. You should be able to migrate betterbird profiles [as you can migrate thunderbird profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer). (**Please make sure to be on the same base version).**

The following instructions are from the official support site for thunderbird (and I have used them in the past often).

On your source computer

1. Connect a device for data transfer, either a local one such as a USB flash drive, or a remote storage drive.
2. Click the menu button, then click Help and select Troubleshooting Information.
3. Locate the "Profile Folder" entry, then click Open Directory.
4. Your Thunderbird profile folder will open in File Browser.
5. Close Thunderbird.
6. From your Thunderbird profile folder in File Browser, go up two levels.
7. Right-click on the .thunderbird folder and select Copy.(.thunderbird is a hidden folder. Make sure you have File Browser set to show hidden files.)
8. Right-click the device you are using to transfer your data, then select Paste.
9. If you are using a local transfer device, remove it safely from the source computer.

Note: This steps can also be used to create a backup of your Thunderbird profile folder.

On your destination computer

1. Connect the same transfer device you have used before to copy your Thunderbird profile folder from the source computer.
2. Right-click on the copy of the Thunderbird profile folder that you created on the transfer device, then select Copy.
3. Open Thunderbird (Close the account setup window if it appears.)
4. Click the menu button, then click Help and select Troubleshooting Information.
5. Locate the "Profile Folder" entry, then click Open Directory.
6. Your Thunderbird profile folder will open in File Browser.
7. Close Thunderbird.
8. From your Thunderbird profile folder in File Browser, go up two levels.
9. Right-click inside the folder, then select Paste. When prompted, choose to replace your current data.